# It is displaying an undefined index in my php

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using the if $_REQUEST statement you mentioned but what I want to do is that if the if statement is met, display the $echo, else display the contents below (session drop down menu and form)

The problem is though is that even though it displays an echo, it displays an undefined notice stating sessionnum is undefined in line 179.

My question is that for the else statement where am I suppose to put the closing bracket in the code below:

```
if (isset($_POST['modulesubmit'])) {

     if($_REQUEST['modulesDrop']==''){

         echo "Please Select a Module from the Drop Down Menu Above";

     }
     else{  

 var_dump($_POST['modulesDrop']);

        $sessionquery = "
             SELECT SessionId, SessionDate, SessionTime, ModuleId
             FROM Session
             WHERE
             (ModuleId = ?)
             ORDER BY SessionDate, SessionTime 
            ";

$sessionqrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($sessionquery);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$sessionqrystmt->bind_param("s",$_POST['modulesDrop']);
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)

$sessionqrystmt->execute(); 

$sessionqrystmt->bind_result($dbSessionId,$dbSessionDate,$dbSessionTime, $dbModuleId);

 $sessionqrystmt->store_result();

$sessionnum = $sessionqrystmt->num_rows();   

    $dataArraySession = array();

 while ( $sessionqrystmt->fetch() ) { 

 $dataArraySession[$dbSessionId]['SessionDate'] = $dbSessionDate; 
 $dataArraySession[$dbSessionId]['SessionTime'] = $dbSessionTime;

}

foreach ($dataArraySession as $sessionId => $sessionData) {



   $sessionHTML = ""; 
   $sessionHTML .= '<select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
   $sessionHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;           
   $sessionHTML .= "<option value='$sessionId'>" . $sessionId . " - " . $sessionData['SessionDate']. " - " . $sessionData['SessionTime'] ."</option>".PHP_EOL;        
   $sessionHTML .= '</select>';

        }
} //closing bracket for else statment
 if ($sessionnum > 0) { //error line is here

 ?>

     <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
     <p>Sessions: <?php echo $sessionHTML; ?><input id="sessionSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="sesionsubmit" /></p>      
    </form>       

<?php

}
else {
 echo "<p>Sorry, You have No Sessions under this Module</p>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you want is to declare any variables that you plan on using inside your IF conditions that will change/reset its value at the top of your page.

Otherwise you will get undefined index warnings. You can try to do @ to silence the warning as well.

```
$sessionnum = 0;

if (isset($_POST['modulesubmit'])) {

     if($_REQUEST['modulesDrop']==''){

         echo "Please Select a Module from the Drop Down Menu Above";

     }
     else{  

 var_dump($_POST['modulesDrop']);

        $sessionquery = "
             SELECT SessionId, SessionDate, SessionTime, ModuleId
             FROM Session
             WHERE
             (ModuleId = ?)
             ORDER BY SessionDate, SessionTime 
            ";

$sessionqrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($sessionquery);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$sessionqrystmt->bind_param("s",$_POST['modulesDrop']);
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)

$sessionqrystmt->execute(); 

$sessionqrystmt->bind_result($dbSessionId,$dbSessionDate,$dbSessionTime, $dbModuleId);

 $sessionqrystmt->store_result();

$sessionnum = $sessionqrystmt->num_rows();   

    $dataArraySession = array();

 while ( $sessionqrystmt->fetch() ) { 

 $dataArraySession[$dbSessionId]['SessionDate'] = $dbSessionDate; 
 $dataArraySession[$dbSessionId]['SessionTime'] = $dbSessionTime;

}

foreach ($dataArraySession as $sessionId => $sessionData) {



   $sessionHTML = ""; 
   $sessionHTML .= '<select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
   $sessionHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;           
   $sessionHTML .= "<option value='$sessionId'>" . $sessionId . " - " . $sessionData['SessionDate']. " - " . $sessionData['SessionTime'] ."</option>".PHP_EOL;        
   $sessionHTML .= '</select>';

        }
} //closing bracket for else statment
 if ($sessionnum > 0) { //error line is here

 ?>

     <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
     <p>Sessions: <?php echo $sessionHTML; ?><input id="sessionSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="sesionsubmit" /></p>      
    </form>       

<?php

}
else {
 echo "<p>Sorry, You have No Sessions under this Module</p>";
}

?>
```